# how can i choose array size in stract type (golang)

Tags: go, struct

i need do something like this :
in go language,please help ,thanks

```
var size_IO= map[string]int{"AI":32,"DI":64,"AO":32}

type IO_point struct{
  Name string 
  }
type AI struct {
    CART [64]IO_point
    Type string
    IO_points [size_IO[Type]]IO_point
}
```

Comment: Describe the higher level problem that you are trying to solve. Why not write `type AI { ... IO_points [32]IO_point }`?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** You cannot do this.

The length of the array is part of type declaration and its value must me resolved at compile time. So it should be constant.

```
const arr_size= 5

type IO_point struct {
    Name string
}
type AI struct {
    CART      [64]IO_point
    Type      string
    IO_points [arr_size]IO_point
}
```

In your situation you need a slice which is a dynamic data structure and more flexible than array. Here it is an example:

```
var size_IO = map[string]int{"AI": 32, "DI": 64, "AO": 32}

type IO_point struct {
    Name string
}
type AI struct {
    CART      [64]IO_point
    Type      string
    IO_points []IO_point
}


func NewAi(cart [64]IO_point, t string) AI {
    return AI{
        CART: cart,
        Type: t,
        IO_points: make([]IO_point, 0, size_IO[t]),
    }
}
```